# En Swift, ¿cómo puedo actualizar una Collection View pulsando un botón (@IBAction)?

Tags: swift, xcode, botón, uicollectionview

Estoy desarrollando (soy primerizo) una aplicación para iPhone con Swift y Xcode que, en una de sus pantallas, tiene una Collection View (**matrixCollectionView**) cuyos valores de las celdas están en un Array **matrix[Int]**.

Cuando estoy pulsando una Celda de la ColletionView en la:

**func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {...}**

puedo cambiar los valores del Array **matrix** y con **self.matrixCollectionView.reloadData()** modifico la vista.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero en la pantalla, además de la Colletion View, tengo un **Button** y pretendo que cuando se pulse este botón, en la **@IBAction** se cambien los valores de matrix y hacer un **self.matrixCollectionView.reloadData()** para actualizar la Vista pero no me funciona, es decir no actualiza la vista de la CollectionView.

Mi pregunta es: **¿cómo puedo actualizar una Collection View pulsando un botón (@IBAction)?**

Gracias

Amplío información:

Estas son las funciones iniciales del CollectioView:

```
// Funciones del collectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matrix.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let celda = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "numeroCelda", for: indexPath) as! matrixCollectionViewCell
        celda.etiqueta2.text = self.imageData[self.matrix [indexPath.row]]
        celda.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        celda.backgroundColor = matrixColor[indexPath.row]
        celda.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return celda
    }
```

En la siguiente función modifico matrix y al hacer reload se actualiza la CollectionView en la pantalla:

```
// Proceso de pulsar celdas
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        let celda = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath        
        // vamos a controlar las pulsaciones teniendo en cuenta las pulsaciones pares
        // var pulsacionesPar: Bool = false

        if numPulsaciones == 0 {                    // la primera pulsación
            celdaPrimera = indexPath                // Guardo indexPath de la Celda 1ª
            valorPrimera = matrix [celdaPrimera.row]    // Guardo el VALOR de la Celda 1ª
          matrixColor[celdaPrimera.row] = colorNovo
          matrix [celdaPrimera.row] = valorNovo

        . . . . . . . . . . . . . 

        self.matrixCollectionView.reloadData()

        . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
        }
    }
```

Pero al pulsar un botón se ejecuta la IBAction siguiente y aquí se actualiza matrix y al hacer reload NO se actualiza la CollectionView en la pantalla:

```
@IBAction func borrarMovimiento2(_ sender: Any) {

        if numPulsaciones > 0 {
            numPulsaciones = 0
            puntosParcial.text = "0"
         matrix = matrixAnterior
            limpiarColores()
            self.matrixCollectionView.reloadData()
        } else {
            if caminosJugador.count > 0 {
                let ultimoGrupo = caminosJugador.last!
                filasEnBlanco = Int(buscarFilasBlanco(matrizFilasBlanco: matrixPartida))
                for pares in ultimoGrupo {
                    // estoy leyendo las parejas del último grupo
                    matrix [pares[0]] = matrixPartidaOriginal[pares[0]]
                    matrix [pares[1]] = matrixPartidaOriginal[pares[1]]
                }
                caminosJugador.remove(at: caminosJugador.count - 1)
                . . . . . . . . . . . 
             . . . . . . . . . . . 

                self.matrixCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
            // No hay nada que borrar
        }
    }
```

Sospecho que funciona en el primer caso porque estoy en una función del sistema y no en el segundo porque estoy en una función particular: no sé.

Seguro que no me he explicado bien y voy a explicar el objetivo final para intentarlo mejor.

Durante el juego (es un juego), el jugador pulsa distintas celdas de la collectionView en el orden que el jugador quiera, yo guardo el log de las pulsaciones y después de su jugada yo quiero repetir sus movimientos (u otros que le sugiera), mostrándolos en pantalla.
Esto lo hago después de su jugada y desde un IBAction de un botón de la pantalla y desde aquí no me hace caso :(

Gracias.

Comment: una vez que cambies el modelo con el recoda debería, puedes hacer recoda solo de las celdas modificadas, pero lo mejor seria que pusieras algo de codigo para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Gracias Spidvmp, he incluido parte del código como me sugieres. Por cierto no sé qué quieres decir con "recoda", supongo que recargar/reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues lo que haría seria insertar o borrar los datos del modelo y después insertar o eliminar los elementos a la collectionview. Para eso debes saber donde vas a poner el elemento nuevo y generar el indexpath que le corresponde y después se lo insertas a la collectionView
Para inserta un nuevo elemento, lo añades al modelo y después generas si indexpath con

```
let ip = IndexPath(rox: x, section: y)
```

y para añadirlo a la Collectionview

```
self.matrixCollectionView.insertItems(at: [ip])
```

Si generas mas de un elementos, después los puedes insertar todos, el insertar es de un array de indexpath

Comment: No sé si he entendido bien lo que propones. Yo lo que hago es modificar todo el contenido del Array (creo que el Array es el 'modelo' que me dices), y pretendo que se actualice todo el collectionView cuando ejecuto matrixCollectionView.reloadData(), quefunciona si lo hago desde una func del Sistema: func viewDidLoad() o func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     .....
    }, pero no desde un IBAction.

Comment: cuando le das al ibaction modificas el array, pues tambien creas los indexpath de los datos que pones y luego se los añades al collection view.